# Automapper UseDestinationValue does not work for List

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I'm trying to map a `List<Sensor>` to `List<Beer>`, I don't want `beer.Name` to be overridden by `sensor.Name`. My code works fine for mapping one to one simple object but it does not work for List

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<Sensor, Beer>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => { opt.UseDestinationValue(); })
            .EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.Id == dest.Id);
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var beer1 = new Beer { Id = 1, Name = "test" };
        var sensor1 = new Sensor { Id = 1, Name = null, Temperature = 20 };
        mapper.Map(sensor1, beer1);
        // beer1.Name == "test" // looks fine!

        var beerList = new List<Beer> { new Beer { Id = 2, Name = "test" } };
        var sensorList = new List<Sensor> { new Sensor { Id = 2, Name = null, Temperature = 20 } };
        mapper.Map(sensorList, beerList);
        // beerList[0].Name == null // it does not work, I wanted it to be "test" as above
```

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing bit in your configuration is `cfg.AddCollectionMappers();` When added all mappings work as you would expect.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
    cfg.CreateMap<Sensor, Beer>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => { opt.UseDestinationValue(); })
        .EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.Id == dest.Id);
});
```

Comment: The `ForMember` doesn't make any sense. You cannot map _into_ a string.

Comment: Thanks! Not quite sure what you mean though. Can you elaborate a bit more? To my knowledge there are two options to ensure that the `Name` property of target object is not overwritten with source: `opt.Ignore()` and `opt.UseDestinationValue()`.

Comment: No. It's just about object identity.